# Check correct formatting of NSString

Tags: objective-c, regex, macos, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have this method in my code:

```
- (void) fullDMXReceived:(NSString*)finalData {
```

It's called when a full line of `<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>` comes in and the line is stored in 'finalData'.

I need some code to determine if 'finalData' is correctly formatted before sending it to a parser:

```
NSArray* allIncomingParseDMX1 = [finalData componentsSeparatedByString:@"<DMX>"];
NSString *parseDMXString1 = [allIncomingParseDMX1 objectAtIndex:1];

NSArray* allIncomingParseDMX2 = [parseDMXString1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"</DMX>"];
NSString *parseDMXString2 = [allIncomingParseDMX2 objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray* allIncoming = [parseDMXString2 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

[redSlider setStringValue:[allIncoming objectAtIndex:0]];
[greenSlider setStringValue:[allIncoming objectAtIndex:1]];
[blueSlider setStringValue:[allIncoming objectAtIndex:2]];
[strobeSlider setStringValue:[allIncoming objectAtIndex:3]];
[strobeRandomSlider setStringValue:[allIncoming objectAtIndex:4]];
[self controlChange];
```

Sometimes, in error, finalData comes in as something other than `<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>` and when it does the app crashes. When finalData is not `<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>` I just want it to ignore it completely and wait for a good one.

I was thinking of having an if statement that matches this criteria:

1. String contains only ONE `<DMX>` and only ONE `</DMX>`.
2. String contains exactly 4 ","
3. String contains at least 5 numbers - as in this case `<DMX>0,0,0,0,0</DMX>` and no greater than 15 numbers - as in this case `<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And use `Regular Expression` to match your strings.

```
//Generate the RegularExpression: <DMX>((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)\,){4}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d))</DMX>
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<DMX>((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d?\\d)\\,){4}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d?\\d))</DMX>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
//Our test strings
NSString *stringMatch = @"<DMX>255,255,255,255,255</DMX>";
NSString *stringNotMatch = @"<DMX>255,255,255,255,299</DMX>";
NSString *stringNotMatch2 = @"<DMX>0,0,0,0</DMX>";


//Get numberOfMatchesInString
NSUInteger resultA = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringMatch
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringMatch length])];

NSUInteger resultB = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringNotMatch
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringNotMatch length])];

NSUInteger resultC = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:stringNotMatch2
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringNotMatch2 length])];

//resultA should be 1. resultB should be 0. resultC should be 0.
NSLog(@"ResultA:%d",resultA);
NSLog(@"ResultB:%d",resultB);
NSLog(@"ResultC:%d",resultC);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting NSRegularExpression! It does EXACTLY what I need. Thanks YuAo!

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I usually have some method dedicated to performing a validity check.

You can add as many checks you can think of to this method, and add new checks as the need arises.

Iterate over your finalData, testing each line for validity, and only extracting the slider values if it is valid.

In your case, a simple first check is

```
- (BOOL) validityCheck:(NSString *) testString
{
    if (!testString)
    {
        // Received nil as a parameter, so just bail here.

        return NO;
    }

    BOOL valid = YES;

    // Look for reasons string may be invalid...

    // Check for expected prefix / suffix...

    if (![testString hasPrefix:@"<DMX>"] || ![testString hasSuffix:@"</DMX>"])
    {
        valid = NO;
    }

    // Check number of elements is in valid range...

    int numOfElements = [testString count];

    if (numOfElements >= 5 && numOfElements <= 15)
    {
        valid = NO;
    }

    // Add more tests for validity...

    // And eventually, return the result...

    return valid;
}
```

You should add some of these techniques generally in your code, because, as well as wanting to detect malformed input, you do not want your code to crash in these circumstances.  For instance, don't assume that when you extract an array using coponentsSeparatedBy... that it will have returned an expected number of elements - check first, and handle errors gracefully.

Comment: NSStrings don't respond to `count`. (You would want to get the substring between the tags, then the components separated by commas, then ask that array for its count.)